# Error when using export-graphml in Neo4j 2.2

Tags: neo4j, graphml

I am trying to use the export-graphml function in Neo4j 2.2. I have downloaded neo4j shell tools and extract it into the lib directory. I am able to export the entire database as a graphml file. However, if I try to export a subset using a query, I receive the following error:

> Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.cypher.export.CypherResultSubGraph.from(Lorg/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/ExecutionResult;Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;Z)Lorg/neo4j/cypher/export/SubGraph;

The statement I used is:

```
export-graphml -o /path/to/file/out.graphml match (n:Person)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]-() WHERE n.id = 12345 return n, r
```

I have tried different variations with the different options (-r, -t) and none work

Comment: It was not built for 2.2.x only for 2.1.x I can create a separate branch for it.