# Export graphml from neo4j community 2.2 using shell tools 2.2

Tags: shell, neo4j, graphml

I downloaded the latest version shell-tools_2.2. I didnt find a lib directory but I extracted the the files to the bin folder. Followed all the remaing instructions shown [here](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools). when I run neo4j-shell and try to export graphml I get the following error

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ export-graphml -o out.graphml match n return n
```

> Unknown command 'export-graphml'

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ help

Available commands: alias begin cd commit create cypher dbinfo drop dump env exp
lain export gsh help index jsh load ls man match merge mknode mkrel mv optional
paths planner profile pwd return rm rmnode rmrel rollback schema set start trav
unwind using with
```

Also tried [Mel18's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544641/error-when-using-export-graphml-in-neo4j-2-2/29560763#29560763) and had the same affect. The help command doesnt seem to show any additional commands regarding export-graphml. What can you suggest?

Neo4j community 2.2.0 Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download the zip manually or use the curl command? I found when I downloaded the zip manually the lib files weren't in there. After using curl, I needed to chmod so the new .jar files were executable. Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked @Mel18, Thanks for your help.
However after using the tool I realised that all the id's are missing in the grapheml file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you view the Neo4jShell.bat and see from which directory it builds it's classpath? You should extract the jars from the download top-level into that directory.

Comment: classpath points to libpath.  Having more luck with linux installation right now.  'rem Setup the classpath
set LIBPATH=""
pushd "%REPO%"
for %%G in (*.jar) do call:APPEND_TO_LIBPATH %%G
popd
goto LIBPATH_END
: APPEND_TO_LIBPATH
set filename=%~1
set suffix=%filename:~-4%
if %suffix% equ .jar set LIBPATH=%LIBPATH%;"%REPO%\%filename%"
goto :EOF

:LIBPATH_END
set CLASSPATH=%LIBPATH%'